# I want to load 'play' button

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I need help!

I need to load the 'play' button in the menu, but it doesn't work and it just shows black screen. The code is here:

```
import pygame
start = False
play = pygame.image.load('game/play.png')
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption('игра')

while run == True:
    pygame.time.delay(50)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    if start == False:
        win.blit(play, (0, 0))
```

Comment: You missed [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) or [`pygame.display.update`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update)

Comment: @Rabbid76 I did it like this, but it still has not been working:
start = False
play = pygame.image.load('game/play.png')
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption('игра')
pygame.display.update()
while run == True:
    pygame.time.delay(50)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    if start == False:
        win.blit(play, (0, 0))

Answer (score 0):

You missed to update the display by by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip). You need to update the display at the end of the application loop after the scene has been drawn. Furthermore, I recommend that you clear the ad every frame:

```py
import pygame
start = False
play = pygame.image.load('game/play.png')
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption('игра')

while run == True:
    pygame.time.delay(50)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # clear disaply
    win.fill(0)

    # draw scene (object)
    if start == False:
        win.blit(play, (0, 0))

    # update display
    pygame.display.flip()              # <--- add this
```